# Questions regarding DictionaryLookup of Mathematica

Tags: assignment

**a.** Make a function `longest[lang_]` that gives the length of the longest word in the dictionary of lang. You should get `longest["French"]=25`

For this part, I have `lang = DictionaryLookup[All];`
`longest[lang_] := Max[StringLength[lang]]`

But this isn't working.

**b.** Now give a list with entries `{language,longest[language]}`.
`Table[{lang[[i]], Length[DictionaryLookup[{lang[[i]], All}]]}, {i, 1, 
  Length[lang]}]`
Again not working

**c.** Make a function `lonegestwords[lang_]` that gives the output `{longest[lang],lang,longwords}` where  `longwords` is the list of the words of longest length in lang.

I tried `longestwords[lang_] := {longest[lang], lang, Select[DictionaryLookup[{lang, All}], StringLength[#] == longest[lang] &]}`

**d.** Now get the list with entries `longestwords[lang]` for all languages and sort it in descending order by the longest word.
I know that I have to use `Sort[longestwords[lang],#2[[1]]<#1[[1]]&]` But since I don't have the function, I can't do it.

Answer (score 3):

You might try the following

```
languages = DictionaryLookup[All]

longest[lang_] := longest[lang] = Max[StringLength[DictionaryLookup[{lang, All}]]]

SortBy[Table[{lang, longest[lang]}, {lang, languages}], Last]

longestwords[lang_] := longestwords[lang] =
   {
     lang, longest[lang], 
     Select[DictionaryLookup[{lang, All}],(StringLength[#] == longest[lang]) &]
   }

SortBy[longestwords /@ languages, #[[2]] &]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but do you know how to do part d?
What I did is `longestwords[lang_] := {longest[lang], lang, Select[DictionaryLookup[{lang, All}],StringLength[#] == longest[lang] &]}` and then `longestwords[All]` but it is taking a long time to give me the answer.

Comment: This can take some time to run because DictionaryLookup downloads some data. Added function for longestwords which I missed first time responding

Comment: This takes less than a minute on my machine, and as little as 10 seconds once the dictionaries are downloaded.